# Ambiguous overload for 'operator>>'

Tags: c++, file, overloading

This is the error I'm getting:

`ambiguous overload for ‘operator>>’ in ‘contestantsInputFile >> contestantName’|`

I am trying to pass a file to a function by reference in order to read a name into a variable called contestantName.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string contestantName = "";
string contestantName(ifstream &);

int main()
{
    ifstream contestantsInputFile;
    contestantsInputFile.open("contestants_file.txt");    
    contestantName(contestantsInputFile);
}


string contestantName(ifstream &contestantsInputFile)
{
    contestantsInputFile >> contestantName; //this is the line with the error
    return contestantName;
}
```

Comment: Where are you declaring the variable `contestantName`?

Comment: You have no variable called `contestantName`.

Comment: oops. actually I did have a variable called contestantName but I accidentally didn't include it in this question because I was trying to cut down the number of lines of code people would have to read. I added the variable in now.

Comment: true... ok I fixed it now to be contestantName

Comment: Now you have two things both named `contestantName` -- one is a `string` and one is a function.  Don't do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your trying to read a function from a std::istream:

```
contestantsInputFile >> contestantName; //this is the line with the error
```

Maybe this is more what you were intending (untested):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string readContestantName(ifstream &); // renamed to be a descriptive verb

int main()
{
    ifstream contestantsInputFile;
    contestantsInputFile.open("contestants_file.txt");    
    std::string contestantName = readContestantName(contestantsInputFile);

    std::cout << "contestant: " << contestantName << "\n";
}


string readContestantName(ifstream &contestantsInputFile)
{
    std::string contestantName; // new variable
    contestantsInputFile >> contestantName; //this is the line with the error
    return contestantName;
}
```